# How to create React application that can be used both as a standard application and as a module in another application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I want to create a Web app in React that can be used both as a standard Web app and as a module in another Web app.

Application I currently work on is a classic admin panel with a couple of navigation tabs. Each tab corresponding one separate functionality, for example, User Profile, User List, User Playground etc. Now my client wants to extrapolate one of those functionalities as a separate module, so it can be used as a standalone application.

So basically I need a module that can be installed as a classic component via npm and included in app, and also used standalone as a classic web app.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Make a component. Stuff it in as the root of your application.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is:

1) You build a module
2) When you want to use it as a part of your application, just install it and include it as any other react npm module
3) When you want to use it as a standalone app, make an empty react app and put your module as application root

Thanks @zfrisch!